# Spring + Appengine can I not use spring security?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

We're building a webapp in our company and spring security configurations going to take time, Is not using spring security a good practice ?. Note that this project has security as high requirement. what are the alternatives ? what about just using filters and web.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and use filter for authentication. There is nothing wrong in "not using spring security"

But spring security offers a lot of ready to use features if you can spent some time on reading their official doc here.
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/features.html

If your requirement is just allowing logged in users to access certain page, go ahead with filters. 
If you want stuff like service layer access security, LDAP, openid consider using spring security